# How to make socket io work in the background android

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, service, socket.io

I have socket IO connected to an android app and it's receiving events via background services. while this is working fine when the app is in foreground. When I close the app or when app goes in background I have confirmed that the sockets are connected but I'm not able to receive events when app is in background.

This is my service

```
const val SOCKET_EVENT = "message:response"

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MService : LifecycleService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var ioSocket: Socket

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ioSocket.connect()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        ioSocket.connect()
        AndroidRemoteDebugger.Log.d("Starting  My Service")
        listenToSocketsEvents()
        return START_STICKY
    }


    private fun listenToSocketsEvents() {
        ioSocket.on(SOCKET_EVENT, onSocketEvent)
    }

    private val onSocketEvent: Emitter.Listener = object : Emitter.Listener {
        override fun call(vararg args: Any?) {
            try {
                val data = args[0] as JSONObject
                //While the main thing about the service is that I'm logging data jhere when I get an 
                // incoming socket event it does log when app is in foreground but when it's in 
                // background it doesn't log
                AndroidRemoteDebugger.Log.v(data.toString())
                val message = data.getJSONObject("message")
                val id = message.getString("id")

                playSound()

                val topic = "message-request"
                val intent = Intent(
                    this@MService,
                    MessageReceiver::class.java
                ).apply {
                    putExtra("messageId", id)
                    putExtra("topic", topic)
                }
                sendBroadcast(intent)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                AndroidRemoteDebugger.Log.e(e.message)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    private fun playSound() {
        val notificationSound: Uri =
            Uri.parse(
                (ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                        packageName) + "/" + R.raw.car_horn
            )
        val ringtone: Ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
            applicationContext,
            notificationSound
        )
        ringtone.play()
    }
}
```

This is my receiver

```
class MessageReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val topic = intent?.getStringExtra("topic")
        val tripId = intent?.getStringExtra("tripId")
        val intent = Intent(Constants.NOTIFICATION).apply {
            putExtra("Notify", topic)
            putExtra("tripId", tripId)
            putExtra("from", Constants.SOCKETS)
        }
        if (context != null) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

While the main thing about the service is that I'm logging something when I get an incoming socket event it does log when app is in foreground but when it's in background it doesn't log

Answer (score 0):

`LifecycleService` will be killed when the app goes in the background/killed.
You should use [ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) to run any background tasks.

From official [doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.

Your sockets are still connected because you don't disconnect the socket when the service gets killed. Always disconnect the socket when you're done with the service to avoid unnecessary resource consumption.